# Is it possible to have two iAds on a single screen?

Tags: ios, iad

I am aware that Apple discourages putting multiple iAds on a single screen. But is it possible to do? I have been playing around with it and have found that when I have two ADBannerView objects, when one gets an ad, the other one immediately unloads. Is this expected?

I don't want to do this to spam my users with tons of ads. I have a complex UIViewController where the ad will need to change location depending on the status of the user activity. It's much easier for me to manage with two banners rather than one, so I can just hide and show them rather than move them around.

Comment: So you trying to double that money you make with ads? :)

Comment: @juniperi I wish! It's not that sinister. I added more of an explanation of what I'm trying to accomplish in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My own experience has been similar, with iAd banners canceling each other out, although I haven't pursued the issue very far.

I will say this, though: there is often a very fine distinction with Apple between "discouraged" and "disallowed."  Even if you squeak by and get approved, your next update might be rejected for that very reason, or it might become a hard-set rule in the next OS version.  Apple maintains its continuity of quality through VERY strict regulation, so it's best not to flirt with bent rules unless you're ready to deal with a lot of trial-and-error.

If you want multiple ads on a single page, I'd probably explore other ad services.  I know that the IGN and ICanHazCheezburger iPhone apps, for example, intersperse ads between every 5th or 6th news item.  Maybe you should research what ad service they use?